# Can gasLimit be infinite?

Tags: gas-limit, gas-estimate

Assuming I have enough Ether, can smart contracts be executed no matter how complex they are as long as I specify a large enough gasLimit?

Hope you can give me some hope, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the transaction size is bounded by the block size.

Hence specifying a gas-limit larger than the block's gas-limit is useless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to know whether the block's gas-limit specified in genesis.json can be infinite?

Comment: @weiwang: On what network?

Comment: Sorry, just forgot to say that it was on my private chain

Comment: @weiwang: Do you know anything **practical** that can be infinite? You'd need a machine with an infinite number of transistors, so no - it can obviously not be infinite per se. Perhaps you mean **arbitrarily large**, in which case, I suppose that again - practical limitations would prevent event that. For example, by the least, the block limit cannot be larger than 2 ^ 256. Using web3.js, it cannot even be larger than 2 ^ 53, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have seen some cases that although you specify a large block gasLimit in the private chain. But because the transaction volume on the private chain is not very dense, the value of gasLimit will gradually drop to the level of the gasLimit of the public chain. I want to know if this situation is theoretically possible on the private chain?

Comment: @weiwang: Sorry, I did not understand your question in the comment above.

Comment: Sorry, my problem may not be clearly described. In some cases, user set the "gasLimit" parameter in genesis.json in their private chain but the gasLimit seems to get automatically adjusted down over time back to the public chain default. Is this phenomenon caused by the mechanism of the blockchain itself? ?

Comment: @weiwang: The gas-limit parameter is something that you set **per transaction**. I don't know genesis.json that well, but I would imagine that you set the **block** gas-limit in it.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. The question I asked you in the comments refers to block gasLimit. The block gasLimit in private chain seems to get automatically adjusted down over time back to the public chain default.

Comment: @weiwang: I don't know about that, just about the question in the title, for which the answer is that using an infinite gas-limit in order to execute a smart contract function is useless, because it is bounded by the gas-limit of the block itself (i.e., the transaction size is bounded by the block size).

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic reply today, which has benefited me a lot. I am very sorry that my comment misled you. Thanks again!